# jquery when / then for recursive ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function getFriends(url) {
    return FB.api(url, function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            if (response.paging && response.paging.next) {
                $.each(response.data, function() {
                    friends.push(this);
                });
                return getFriends(response.paging.next);
            } else {
                console.error(friends);
            }
        } else {
            console.error("facebook friends couldn't been retrieved ");
        }
    });
}

$.when(getFriends("/me/friends")).then(
    function() {
        console.log('getFriends finished');
    });
```

i want to make sure that fb calls finished when the then() block executed but had no chance. is there a way to implement this ?

thanks

Comment: does `FB.api()` return a promise object? If not, then you can't use it with `$.when`.

Comment: The FB API call probably won't return a jQuery style Deferred / promise object. Instantiate your own `$.Deferred` inside your function, return the instance and resolve it manually inside the FB API call's callback.

Comment: The [FB.api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/) is not jQuery depended and thus does not return a promise object. So when you pass the response of `getFriends` to `$.when` the `then` callback is immediately called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook JS SDK does not implement jQuery style promise objects / `$.Deferred`s but you can easily create an instance on your own like:

```
function getFriends(url) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    FB.api(url, function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            if (response.paging && response.paging.next) {
                $.each(response.data, function() {
                    friends.push(this);
                });
                return getFriends(response.paging.next);
            } else {
                console.log(friends);
            }
            dfd.resolve();
        } else {
            console.error("facebook friends couldn't been retrieved ");
            dfd.reject();
        }
    });
    return dfd;
}

getFriends("/me/friends").done(
    function() {
        console.log('getFriends finished');
    }
);
```

Comment: Although "then" reads as if it means do this and "then" do that, in reality it is another incarnation of the deprecated ["pipe"](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) where you can change what gets passed in the deferred's resolve and reject calls. In the example above if you add a "done", the callback will be called with undefined, i.e.: `.then(...).done(function(x){})` (x is undefined)

In sum, it's best to use **.done** instead of **.then** (unless you really want to change what gets "returned" in the promise)

Comment: @Rui +1 for that, I just didn't want to add too much confusion by changing stuff, but I guess I'll go for that now as you are totally right.

Comment: @m90 i tried as you said but this time done() part is not executed.

Comment: What does it log in your console? An error or the list of friends?

Comment: ok i get the idea.i guess recursively creating deferred objects was the main problem. now i created single deferred object and pass it to the `getFriends` method. it is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but a working example that demo's how to go about it:

**Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/LE2e3/4/)**

```
function doStuff() {

    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    alert ("loaded");
    setTimeout(function(){
        dfd.resolve("response - success");
    }, 5000);
    return dfd.promise();

}


$.when(doStuff()).then(function(status) {
    alert(status);
});
```